# Move rows and columns of an association matrix

Tags: matrix, dataset, associations

**Example data:**

```
dt =
  <|"joe" -> <|"C1" -> 103, "C2" -> 104, "C3" -> 105, "C4" -> 107, "C5" -> 114|>, 
   "tim" -> <|"C1" -> 101, "C2" -> 102, "C3" -> 109, "C4" -> 101, "C5" -> 111|>, 
   "ann" -> <|"C1" -> 102, "C2" -> 103, "C3" -> 103, "C4" -> 105, "C5" -> 114|>, 
   "bob" -> <|"C1" -> 103, "C2" -> 103, "C3" -> 103, "C4" -> 104, "C5" -> 113|>|>;
```

What I have done so far:

```
move[dt_, ky_, {f_, t_}] :=
 Module[{kr, as, pf, pt},
  kr = Range @ Length @ ky;
  as = Thread[ky -> kr];
  pf = Lookup[as, f, -1];
  pt = Lookup[as, t, -1];
  If[pf == -1 || pt == -1, Return[{}]];
  If[pf > pt,
   DeleteDuplicates @ Insert[kr, pf, pt],
   Reverse @ DeleteDuplicates @ Reverse @ Insert[kr, pf, pt + 1]]
  ]

MoveColumn[dt_, ps_] :=
 Query[All, move[dt, Keys @ dt[[1]], ps]] @ dt

MoveRow[dt_, ps_] :=
 Query[move[dt, Keys @ dt, ps]] @ dt
```

**Examples:**

Move last column before first column:

```
MoveColumn[dt, {"C5", "C1"}] // Dataset
```

[image]

Move first column behind last column:

```
MoveColumn[dt, {"C1", "C5"}] // Dataset
```

[image]

Move some column behind another:

```
MoveColumn[dt, {"C3", "C4"}] // Dataset
```

[image]

Row moves follow the same logic:

```
MoveRow[dt, {"tim", "ann"}] // Dataset
```

[image]

**My question:**

How can I move two or more contiguous columns / rows like:

```
MoveColumn[dt, {{"C5", "C4"}, "C1"}]
```

to get {C5, C4, C1, C2, C3}

or

```
MoveColumn[dt, {{"C4", "C5"}, "C1"}]
```

to get {C4, C5, C1, C2, C3}?

Comment: Does something along the lines of: `Query[{1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 4}]@dt` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is probably the best way for associations with not too many columns or rows. But it becomes tedious with large matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the separate question of defining a function to give the desired permutation, here's a way. There is probably a much more clever way.

```
RepositionBefore[{moveIdx_Integer, sentinalIdx_Integer}] := 
  RepositionBefore[{{moveIdx}, sentinalIdx}];
RepositionBefore[{moveIdxs_List, sentinalIdx_Integer}][length_Integer] := 
  RepositionBefore[{moveIdxs, sentinalIdx}][Range@length];
RepositionBefore[{moveIdxs_List, sentinalIdx_Integer}][list_List] :=
  With[
    {moveVals = Extract[list, List /@ moveIdxs],
     stayVals = ReplacePart[list, List /@ moveIdxs -> Null]},
    DeleteCases[Flatten[Insert[stayVals, moveVals, sentinalIdx]], Null]]
```

Usage:

```
RepositionBefore[{{4, 5}, 1}][{"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"}]
(* {"C4", "C5", "C1", "C2", "C3"} *)

RepositionBefore[{{4, 5}, 1}][5]
(* {4, 5, 1, 2, 3} *)
```

You can feed it as a query to your dataset:

```
dtDataset[RepositionBefore[{4, 2}][4], RepositionBefore[{{5, 4}, 1}][5]]
```

[image]

**Update**

Thanks to @CarlWoll for reminding me that Query works for associations, not just datasets.:

```
Query[RepositionBefore[{4, 2}][4], RepositionBefore[{{5, 4}, 1}][5]][dt]
(* <|"joe" -> <|"C5" -> 114, "C4" -> 107, "C1" -> 103, "C2" -> 104, "C3" -> 105|>, 
     "bob" -> <|"C5" -> 113, "C4" -> 104, "C1" -> 103, "C2" -> 103, "C3" -> 103|>, 
     "tim" -> <|"C5" -> 111, "C4" -> 101, "C1" -> 101, "C2" -> 102, "C3" -> 109|>, 
     "ann" -> <|"C5" -> 114, "C4" -> 105, "C1" -> 102, "C2" -> 103, "C3" -> 103|>|> *)
```

Comment: Thank you, @lericr, +1. It does what I want, and it should be easy to go from  `{Q5, Q4}` to `{5, 4}` (I can do that myself).

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to work with `Dataset`, then you can permute the rows and columns directly. So, let's say we have,

```
dtDataset = Dataset[dt]
```

Then you can do this:

```
dtDataset[{"ann", "tim", "bob"}, {"C5", "C1", "C3"}]
```

[image]

So, all you need to do is specify the permutations you want. If you still want a representation of a permutation like this,

```
{{"C4", "C5"}, "C1"}
```

Then just write a function that creates that permutation. Let's say it's `MyPermutation`. Then we'd want something like

```
MyPermutation[{{4, 5}, 1}][{"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"}]
```

to yield

```
{"C5", "C4", "C1", "C2", "C3"}
```

How to do that is independent of the association and dataset. I'd consider that a separate question (or at least an easier question than one that's polluted by the unnecessary context of Associations and Datasets.